# Opening an uploaded photo in Flask

Tags: python, flask, amazon-s3, upload

I am trying to send photos that are uploaded to my Flask website to an S3 bucket. The issue that I am having is `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'myPic.JPG'`. How do I access (and then open) a file (specifically an image) that the user has just entered into a form? I can use `photos.save(x)` successfully, so what is preventing me from using `open()`?

```py
photos = UploadSet('photos', IMAGES)

@application.route("/upload", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def upload():
    form = UploadForm()
    uploaded_files = request.files.getlist("photo")
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        for w in uploaded_files:
            with open(w.filename) as file_up:
                conn.upload_fileobj(file_up, bucket_name, 'gallery/fulls/'+filename)
```

***TRACEBACK***:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/senrab/Desktop/sdchapel.org/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2328, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/senrab/Desktop/sdchapel.org/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2314, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/Users/senrab/Desktop/sdchapel.org/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1760, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/senrab/Desktop/sdchapel.org/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 36, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/senrab/Desktop/sdchapel.org/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2311, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/senrab/Desktop/sdchapel.org/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1834, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Users/senrab/Desktop/sdchapel.org/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1737, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/senrab/Desktop/sdchapel.org/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 36, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/senrab/Desktop/sdchapel.org/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1832, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/senrab/Desktop/sdchapel.org/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1818, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/senrab/Desktop/sdchapel.org/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_login/utils.py", line 261, in decorated_view
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/senrab/Desktop/sdchapel.org/app/routes.py", line 306, in upload
    with open(w.filename) as file_up:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'P8044182.JPG'
```

***EDIT:***

I have edited the function slightly and I think that I am closer to the answer:

**New Function**:

```py
photos = UploadSet('photos', IMAGES)

@application.route("/upload", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def upload():
    form = UploadForm()
    uploaded_files = request.files.getlist("photo")
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        for w in uploaded_files:
            # HERE IS THE ALTERATION:
            with open(w.stream.read()) as file_up:
                conn.upload_fileobj(file_up, bucket_name, 'gallery/fulls/'+filename)
```

**Traceback**:

```
File "/Users/senrab/Desktop/sdchapel.org/app/routes.py", line 307, in upload
    with open(w.stream.read()) as file_up:
ValueError: embedded null byte
```

I am guessing that this means that I have to alter the way that I am opening the file?

Comment: Are you able to see the uploaded files in the local directory?

Comment: It would be very helpful if you add the whole stacktrace of the exception.

Comment: UploadSet saves files to a specific folder (check here: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/fileuploads/ ) did you try to use folder + filename to access the file?

Comment: I have tried using folder + filename, but that led to the same error. I have edited the question, with a slight change in the function that gets me, I think, closer to having the file uploaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By eliminating `with open(...)` I can successfully upload the image.

```py
photos = UploadSet('photos', IMAGES)

@application.route("/upload", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def upload():
    form = UploadForm()
    uploaded_files = request.files.getlist("photo")
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        for w in uploaded_files:
            conn.upload_fileobj(file_up, bucket_name, 'gallery/fulls/'+filename)
```